# c# - represent array of integers in bit field

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, bitmap, integer

i have an array of integer like

```
int [] intArray;
intArray = new int[3] { 1, 2 , 40 , 45 , 50};
```

the array contains numbers from 1- to 50

i want to convert this array to one bit represent like

```
100001000010000............11
```

who can i do this in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long bitField = 0;

foreach (int bit in intArray)
    bitField |= 1l << (bit - 1);
```

This answer assumes 1-based bit numbers as per your question.  If you would like 0 to refer to the first bit, simply change `(bit - 1)` to `bit`.

Comment: An alternative: `long bitField = intArray.Aggregate(0l, (a, x) => a | (1l << (x - 1)));`